# Apply zoom and also flipping to image wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have xaml defined for an image as follows:

```
 <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>                  
                    <Image x:Name="documentPage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill">    
                        <Image.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.LayoutTransform>
                    </Image>                     
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

and on buttons for zoom in and zoom out I increment the ScaleFactor by 0.1 (zoom in) or decrement by 0.1 (zoom out).

Now I also want to apply flipping the image as well...like flip it vertically or horizontally....How do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: You could always negate the scale x/y property in your layout transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the TransformGroup that you've applied to LayoutTransform you can put as many scale transforms as you want, you could bind another scale transform to a property.

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"/>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

instead of -1 and 1 in the second transform bind them to a property in your viewmodel (obviously a converter will be required if your flipx and flipy properties are boolean)

Here I've created a simple example that shows all of the features from your question using a converter to convert boolean properties into a scale transforms ScaleX and ScaleY.

[image]

XAML

```
  <Window x:Class="flipx.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:flipx"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Ellipse Grid.Row="0"  Width="100" Height="100">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush >
                        <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF2300FF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
                <Ellipse.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"/>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding FlipX, Converter={local:BooleanToScaleConverter}}" ScaleY="{Binding FlipY, Converter={local:BooleanToScaleConverter}}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Ellipse.LayoutTransform>
            </Ellipse>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding FlipX}">FlipX</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding FlipY}">FlipY</CheckBox>         
                <Slider Minimum="0.001" Maximum="5" Value="{Binding ScaleFactor}" Width="150"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace flipx
{
    public class BooleanToScaleConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        static BooleanToScaleConverter converter;

        public BooleanToScaleConverter() { }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (converter == null) converter = new BooleanToScaleConverter();
            return converter;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool boolValue = (bool)value;
            return boolValue ? -1 : 1;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public double ScaleFactor
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleFactorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleFactorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleFactorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleFactor", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(1d));

        public bool FlipX
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(FlipXProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FlipXProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipXProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FlipX", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool FlipY
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(FlipYProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FlipYProperty, value); }
        }        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipYProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FlipY", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks andy...could you elaborate a bit ... I am new to wpf...how do i use a converter? Thank again...

Comment: A converter is used when binding a property on your view to a property in the view model that don't have exactly matching types (or you want to do some other manipulation) it does exactly what it sounds like it does, just converts the view model property into something else for the view.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once. Thanks a million for helping out beginners. Thanks again